# Sql Server pick only consonants from name

Tags: sql-server, string, insert

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [PRODUCTS].[PRODUCERS](
[ID] [bigint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [id_producers]  DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR 
[producersID_SEQ]),
[VAT_CODE] [varchar](255) NULL,
[CODE] [varchar](45) NULL,
[NAME] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
[NOTE] [varchar](255) NULL,
[TFACTORY] [varchar](11) NULL DEFAULT ('@@'),
[fitting_code] [varchar](3) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [SQL160208104403390] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

at every insert in this table, the value in column "fitting code" should be created picking the first three consonants from the value in column "name"

```
insert into products.PRODUCERS (fitting_code) select ...
```

Example:

```
Ponzio Pilato => PNZ
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function which deletes vowels in string. Then get first 3 character from return value. Function should be like this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_REMOVEL_VOWELS (@STRING VARCHAR(max))
returns varchar(max)
as 
begin
RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@STRING, 'A', ''), 'E', ''), 'O', ''), 'U', ''), 'I', '')
END


SELECT DBO.FN_REMOVEL_VOWELS('INFORMATION SYSTEM')
```

//This will return NFRMTN SYSTM

Or you can do it in your sql query like this

```
INSERT INTO products.PRODUCERS (NAME, fitting_code)
VALUES(@NAME, SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@NAME, 'A', ''), 'E', ''), 'O', ''), 'U', ''), 'I', ''), 1, 3))
```

Comment: The list of vowels differs between different collations.

Comment: Which alphabet do you use? Isn't it constant? @RemusRusanu

Comment: Well, what if the string comes from a column with Turkish collation? You should be familiar with the problem http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html Ditto for many more characters, like `ü`. And, the function being VARCHAR not NVARCHAR, you can't even rely on the characters itself, it depends on the *collation* of the original column to make sense.

Comment: I think you can not do this for all alphabet. For example Russion or Chinese alphabet. All letters are different.